# Read a text file and write the texts in chunks of 1000 characters keeping the words intact in C#

Tags: c#

I am trying to read a file and split the text after every 1000 characters. But I want to keep the words intact. So it should just split at the space. If the 1000th character is not a space, then split at the first space just before or just after it. Any idea how to do that? I am also removing the extra spaces from the text.

```
                 while ((line = file.ReadLine()) != null)
        {

            text = text + line.Trim();
            noSpaceText = Regex.Replace(text, @"\r\n?|\n/", "");      

        }

        List<string> rowsToInsert = new List<string>();

        int splitAt = 1000; 
        for (int i = 0; i < noSpaceText.Length; i = i + splitAt)
        {
                if (noSpaceText.Length - i >= splitAt)
            {
                rowsToInsert.Add(noSpaceText.Substring(i, splitAt));
            }
            else
                    rowsToInsert.Add(noSpaceText.Substring(i, 
            ((noSpaceText.Length - i))));
        }

        foreach(var item in rowsToInsert)
          {
            Console.WriteLine(item);
          }
```

Comment: Use substring to get first 1001 characters from the string. Check the last character is space. If yes then write that to text file. If not read substring from start to last space character in the 1001 character string and write that to text file. That's how you do it.

Comment: Can you share the code you gave written so far? And explain what issue you are facing with that?

Comment: You could Split you text and iterate over that array and count the length +1 for each split

Comment: `just before or just after it` you need to first decide what you need to do exactly.

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya, I am struggling to check for the spaces there.

Comment: @Pac0, anything is fine. Lets say just before it.

Comment: @TinoZ, your answer doesn't tell me how to check for spaces

Comment: You should store `noSpaceText.Substring(i, splitAt +1)` in some variable and the check if its last character is a space.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, just typed this non tested solution which should do the trick:

```
public static List<string> SplitOn(this string input, int charLength, char[] seperator)
        {
            List<string> splits = new List<string>();
            var tokens = input.Split(seperator);
            // -1 because first token adds 1 to length
            int totalLength = -1;
            List<string> segments = new List<string>;
            foreach(var t in tokens)
            {
                if(totalLength + t.Length+1 > charLength)
                {
                    splits.Add(String.Join(" ", segments));
                    totalLength = -1;
                    segments.Clear();
                }
                totalLength += t.Length + 1;
                segments.Add(t);
            }
            if(segments.Count>0)
            {
                splits.Add(String.Join(" ", segments));
            }
            return splits;
        }
```

It's an extension Method, which splits an input text in segments by whitespaces, means, i iterate over an array with just words. Then counting the length of each segment, checking for totallength and add it to result list.

Comment: glad i can help.

Answer (score 0):

An alternate solution:

```
public static List<string> SplitString(string stringInput, int blockLength)
{
    var output = new List<string>();
    var count = 0;
    while(count < stringInput.Length)
    {
        string block = "";
        if(count + blockLength > stringInput.Length)
        {
            block = stringInput.Substring(count, stringInput.Length - count);   
        }
        else
        {
            block = stringInput.Substring(count, blockLength + 1);  
        }

        if(block.Length < blockLength)
        {
            output.Add(block);  
            count += block.Length;
        }
        else if(block.EndsWith(" "))
        {
            output.Add(block);
            count = count+blockLength + 1;
        }
        else
        {   
            output.Add(block.Substring(0, block.LastIndexOf(" ")));
            count = count + block.LastIndexOf(" ") +1;
        }
    }

    return output;
}
```